# perl unable to copy contents of file and print it

Tags: perl

I need to read/copy the contents of a file(test.pl) just as the way it is formatted and email it.

I am using the following code but I am unable to print anything out.

I get this error even though the file exists in the same directory.

```
Failed: No such file or directory
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

open my $fh, '<', 'test.pl '
    or die "Failed: $!\n";

my $text = do {
    local $/;
    <$fh>
};

close $fh
    or die "Failed again: $!\n";

print $text, "\n";
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like there is an extra space in the filename you are trying to open.  In your open statement, try changing `'test.pl '` to `'test.pl'`.

Comment: you are right. an extra space. :-) will accept your answer in 5 mins once it lets me.

Comment: Situations like this are more easily seen if your `die` included not only the error but also the name of the object; viz; my $file=q(test.pl);open my $fh, '<', $file or dise "Failed to open '$file': $!\n";  In this snippet, single quote bound the file name and if the `open` fails and you are more likely to see the error.

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to read files names from STDIN (user's input), you may want to trim them either by using regex (s/^\s+//....) or `Text::Trim` among other validations.

Comment: The downvote wasn't mine, but I'll speculate that it is because you're providing advice, but not directly answering the question.  As such, a comment to the question would have been more appropriate.